# java fx Context menu will show in wrong position if the Swt dialog change the location

Tags: javafx, swt

I have the following testing code, running in linux env(like ubuntu). The context menu will show in wrong position intead of the menubutton's neighbour.
The screenshot like this [image]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import application.SWTTestUtil;
import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class ContextMenuTestingComposite extends Composite {
  private FXCanvas fxCanvas;

  public ContextMenuTestingComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, SWT.NONE);
    setLayout(new FillLayout());
    fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(this, SWT.NONE);
    Parent root = getRoot();
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    fxCanvas.setScene(scene);
  }

  protected Parent getRoot() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getURL());
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    Parent root = null;
    try {
      root = fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return root;
  }

  protected URL getURL() {
    return getClass().getResource("contextmenuTestingComposite.fxml");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(800, 600);
    shell.setText("test the context menu");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    centerShellToPrimaryWindow(shell.getDisplay(), shell);
    ContextMenuTestingComposite composite = new ContextMenuTestingComposite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

  public static void centerShellToPrimaryWindow(Display display, Shell shell) {
    Monitor primary = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
    Rectangle bounds = primary.getBounds();
    Rectangle rect = shell.getBounds();

    int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - rect.width) / 2;
    int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - rect.height) / 2;
    shell.setLocation(x, y);
  }

}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" />
      <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
        </items>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="59.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </MenuButton>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

is there anyone know this issue? this problem will be fixed by move the shell a little bit.therfore, how to do it by program?

Comment: By the way, the code works well in windows.

Comment: I see the same problem in a similar application. Context menu for JavaFX widgets appear in the wrong location if JavaFX is embedded in SWT FXCanvas, and the FXCanvas has been moved. In your example, `centerShellToPrimaryWindow()` performs such a the move, and the context menu then appears where the Shell used to be. This only happens on Linux. Manually moving the Shell once more tends to correct the problem. I tried invoking `layout()` from a listener to the 'showing' property of the button to force a re-computation of the popup location just before the popup appears, but this did not help.

Comment: yes. I aslo try the `Layout()` method and failed to solve the problem. And After I debug, it seems this is a bug of GTK. It will return a wrong position when fxcanvas calculate the postion of popup menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem in Linux and here is the workaround - **"shake" the SWT dialog (shell) once when it's activated.**

```
shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e) {
       Point p = shell.getLocation();
       shell.setLocation(p.x, p.y - 1);
       shell.setLocation(p.x, p.y);

       shell.removeShellListener(this);
   }
});
```

Hope it's helpful to you.